# Django - Dynamically get the appropriate data based on the dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, django

I have a template where I have a dropdown. I would like to display some data based on the dropdown value selected. The data is fetched from the DB.

As I have no idea about ajax or jquery, I need help here to dynamically display the content based on the dropdown selected.

Example: Say my dropdown is [1,2,3,4]. When user selected 1, it should display ONE in my HTML, if user selected 2 then it should display TWO and so on.

Can some please share me the HTML code for the above example (with ajax or jquery)?

Comment: You are mixing stuff up here. jQuery has nothing to do with Ajax. Find a basic tutorial on Ajax calls and work your way up. In your case you would have some kind of submit/ select button. When this button is clicked the Ajax call is triggered with `onclick="AjaxExample(event)"` and so on. Come back here when you wrote some code and have a specific problem.

Comment: I have written the code such that when dropdown is changed, the dropdown text is displayed on the screen. However what I need now is, instead of the text, I would like to use this text and perform some operation and return that value on to the template. Example: Say my dropdown in displaying some plans like quarterly, yearly, etc. When I select yearly, I would like to fetch details of the yearly plan (like description, price,etc) and display on the screen.

Comment: My code  `{% block content %}
<div><br>
 {% if name %}
  <label>Plans:<label>
  <select id="getPlanDetails">
      {% for i in planNames %}
      <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
  
  <div id="results"></div>
 {% endif %}

</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#getPlanDetails").on("change", function(){
    var selected =  $(this).val();
    $("#results").html("You selected: " + selected);
  })
</script>      
{% endblock %`

Answer (score 0):

**Using JQuery:**

- Pass whole options as key value pair, ex: {key : {key:val, ...}, ...}
- Use JQuery to show and hide equivalent sub options when an
  option is clicked.

**Using AJAX:**

- When an option clicked, send an AJAX request to the server.
- Fetch its sub options and show in the browser using JQuery.